# Universal App, simulator detects ~iphone .xib's but device still displays ipad .xibs

Tags: ios, universal, universal-binary, ios-universal-app

I created an iPad only app and now the client would like me to make it universal. I have created new .xib's, which are automatically detected via the ~iphone suffix and work fine on the simulator. However, when I run it on my iPhone 4s to debug, only the iPad .xib's seem to show up. Thanks!

Comment: It seems I managed to find the solution, yes, mere minutes after posting the question. I changed the "Build Active Architecture Only" setting to YES. That did the trick.

Comment: So add your solution as an answer and accept it. It might help some people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, could you show me how you create a `UIViewController` inside your app? Because we have two options:

1. You are doing the right thing, and you are sub-classing most of the classes so you have an `-iPhone` and an `-iPad` version.
2. You are putting `ifs` and checking what kind of device you are on.

What changes have you made on the target setting's?